# Quantum Mechanics or Classical Mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

I'm just a student of grade 11 but, I was interested in knowing about Physics much deeper. In order to start my interest in Physics, I watched this video of Quantum Physics NOVA : [Quantum Physics(NOVA)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVPIGtGcYE0)

I have some questions in mind :

$\bullet$ Is [Quantum Mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mechanics) also applicable for **massive** objects like Human Beings, Animals etc. (in comparison with the **small atoms**) ?

$\bullet$ How much does Quantum Mechanics affects the rules that we have studied yet, like in **Newtonian Mechanics** and **Classical Mechanics** ?

$\bullet$ Has Quantum Mechanics been successful in defining the movement of atoms and other negligibly small objects like sub-atomic particles etc. ? Or is there something yet to come...?

$\bullet$ While, I know that any theory is simply *NOT* based on **calculations** or only on **experiments**. Has Quantum Mechanics been able to define all the rules with the help of Experiments etc.?

$\bullet$ As a student, I'm basically confused that which theory is the **most** accurate and **applicable** in real life. So, which theory is the most accurate and applicable to the reality?

$\bullet$ After watching the video (linked at the start), I was not able to conclude whether Quantum Mechanics is based on **accuracy** or on **probability** ?

$\star$ I'm sorry, I understand that these questions are much broad and may be concluded as foolish or meaningless questions, but, as a student these were the questions which came in my mind. I will appreciate a lot if anyone can help me in clearing my doubts!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep in mind that this site wants single questions at a time. I will answer with simple answers.

> ∙ Is Quantum Mechanics also applicable for massive objects like Human Beings, Animals etc. (in comparison with the small atoms) ?

You will learn if you continue in physics that the underlying framework of nature as far as we have explored and validated is quantum mechanical. Are bricks applicable to buildings?

> ∙ How much does Quantum Mechanics affects the rules that we have studied yet, like in Newtonian Mechanics and Classical Mechanics ?

Classical theories are self contained and their overlap with quantum mechanics comes where classical theories fail, as in the [photoelectric effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect), and the [black body radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation). Otherwise classical theories emerge smoothly  from quantum mechanics when dimensions get larger than the nanometer scales.

> ∙ Has Quantum Mechanics been successful in defining the movement of atoms and other negligibly small objects like sub-atomic particles etc. ? Or is there something yet to come...?

Yes it has, as you will find if you continue your studies. It has never been falsified by any experiment to date.

> ∙ While, I know that any theory is simply NOT based on calculations or only on experiments. Has Quantum Mechanics been able to define all the rules with the help of Experiments etc.?

Theories describe nature if they are validated by experiments. Even one false prediction requires a redrawing of the theory

> ∙ As a student, I'm basically confused that which theory is the most accurate and applicable in real life. So, which theory is the most accurate and applicable to the reality?

In real life classical mechanics, electrodynamics, thermodynamics  suffices unless you want to understand transistors, quantum computation etc. You have to learn the math to deal with the underlying quantum mechanical framework

> ∙ After watching the video (linked at the start), I was not able to conclude whether Quantum Mechanics is based on accuracy or on probability ?

The theoretical predictions of quantum mechanics are probabilistic, they give the probability of getting a specific measurement. Classical theories predict for example trajectories, whose indeterminacy depends on experimental and calculational errors. In quantum mechanics there is a basic indeterminacy for any measurement coming from  the basics of the theory but that does not mean that there are no predictions that can be falsified.

Answer (score 2):

> Is quantum mechanics for massive objects, like human beings?

In principle, we can write down the Hamiltonian for virtually any system, even if it is composed of atoms on the order of $10^{20}$, and solve the Schrödinger equation,

$$H\lvert \psi \rangle = E \lvert \psi \rangle$$

However, in practice, it would be extremely tedious, and currently modern computers are simply not capable of solving the equation numerically. In addition, it is not illuminating to even know $\psi$ for a system as complex as described.

---

> How much does quantum mechanics affect the rules we have studied, e.g. Newtonian mechanics?

As we incorporate further realism into our physical models, e.g. by including relativistic effects, quantum mechanical effects, we potentially increase the accuracy of our predictions. However, one should always pick the most appropriate for a problem - e.g. don't apply QM to a football trajectory. One formulation does not 'affect' the other, but rather reveals its short shortcomings.

---

> Has quantum mechanics been successful in defining the movement of atoms and other particles?

The quantum mechanical model of the hydrogen-like ion is arguably the most famous, and offers quite accurate predictions of, for example, the energy levels of the electron. The approach is vastly different from classical physics; the electron does not follow a fixed orbit. Instead, we assign probabilities for the electron to be within a particular volume; specifically,

$$P(V)=\int_V \mathrm{d}^3x \, |\psi|^2$$

for a normalized wave function, $\psi$, which is the solution to the equation,

$$E\psi = \left( -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2 - \frac{Ze^2}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r}\right)\psi$$

For more complex atoms, or even molecules, numerical approximation is required. A popular approach is perturbation theory, whereby we model the current system as being a soluble system, i.e.

$$H=H_0+\lambda H_I$$

where $H_0$ is the known system, $H_I$ is the perturbation, and $\lambda$ determines the strength of the perturbation. (If dimensionless, $\lambda < 1$ suggests a weakly perturbed system).

---

Regarding accuracy and probability. One could argue quantum mechanics is a more accurate model of Nature. Often, it may be the case that the predictions are also more precise. However, if we attempt to model a complex system with quantum mechanics, and have to resort to poor numerical approximations, the predictions may be worse than had we applied a simpler model - possibly.

Comment: Hello JamalS ! Thanks for answering my doubts, but, I'm just a 16 year old beginner... so, may be I will need time to understand this all. Just wanted to let you know, that I have looked at it. :)

Comment: Also, in the video there was something mentioned like.. connection between two objects.. I don't know what does it spell actually, can you help in this?

Comment: @KushashwaRaviShrimali: The video is 50+ minutes long; please tell me what part you need clarified.

Comment: intangle particles ... something like this :( Something about 35:00 minutes.

Comment: @KushashwaRaviShrimali: Quantum entanglement :) That's really for a separate question; it would not be appropriate to update the answer.

Comment: Oh that is Entanglement..! Nice. It is really interesting, and yeah, its okay, I just was not sure what it spells, everything else about is okay :D

Comment: Sorry, my net stopped working. very sorry.